# Equal spacing, scaling in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

Is there a way i can space the inner shape at exactly 1 cm from all sides with the outer shape? [image]

Comment: Draw one shape instead, add a stroke as thick as required, and Expand it. Set no fill, and apply a stroke.

Comment: Hey @BillyKerr why not make that an answer? It's short but it _is_ an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Luciano, no I don't want any challengers. Shhh... https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT2zS.png

Comment: @Luciano I will!  Sorry Joonas!

Answer (score 3):

1. Make the first shape. Make sure it's selected
2. From menu do:`Object > Path > Offset Path...` input `1cm` as the offset

Sometimes offset turns smooth curves into tighter ones that look a bit off. You can mitigate this a little by applying a tiny bit of `Object > Path > Simplify...`. Sometimes it may help to apply Simplify before the offset.

Answer (score 3):

1. Draw one shape, add a stroke and change the stroke width to 1cm, set the fill to none.
2. Click *Ojbect > Expand*. Then OK.
3. Set the fill to none, and apply a stroke.

[image]